# Necessary to implement fetch_token if using access token immediately?

Tags: authlib

When using [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/) with a service like [GitHub](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/apps.html#github), is it necessary to implement [`fetch_token`](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#cache-database) if we only want to use the token once in order to retrieve a user's profile (from https://api.github.com/user)? I see that "If OAuth login is what you want ONLY, you don’t need `fetch_token` at all," though technically we want a bit more than that, since we're calling `github.get` after calling `github.authorize_access_token`:

```
import os

from authlib.flask.client import OAuth
from authlib.client.apps import github
from flask import Flask, redirect, session, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
oauth = OAuth(app)
app.config["GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"] = os.getenv("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID")
app.config["GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET"] = os.getenv("GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET")
app.config["GITHUB_CLIENT_KWARGS"] = {"scope": "user:email"}
github.register_to(oauth)

...

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for("authorize", _external=True)
    return github.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route("/authorize")
def authorize():
    token = github.authorize_access_token()
    user = github.get("user").json()
    session["login"] = user["login"]
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

It appears that `github.get("user")` succeeds (as does a call to, e.g., `github.profile`) even without storing `token` in, e.g., `session` or a database and returning it via calls to a `fetch_token` function?

Comment: you don't need a `fetch_token`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up (and library)! Via what mechanism is an OAuth2 access token for the just-authenticated user associated with the outgoing `github.get` request? It looks like `authlib/flask/client/oauth.py` uses `flask.session` to save an OAuth1 request token for the current user, but I'm not sure I followed how `github.get` (i.e., `OAuthClient.get`) and, in turn, `OAuthClient.request` know which access token to use? Is it [authlib/client/oauth2.py#L335](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/client/oauth2.py#L335) that associates an access token with the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need a `fetch_token`.

```
github.authorize_access_token()
print(github.session.token)
```